# elasticsearch python pycharm

Tags: python, elasticsearch, pycharm

I am trying to run a very simple insertion to Elasticsearch in Python:

```
es = Elasticsearch({'host': 'localhost', 'port': 9200})
res = es.index(index='data-client_dev', doc_type='test', id=2, body={'author': 'Christophe'}, timeout=60)
print(res['created'])
```

But I keep having the error pasted at the end.
I am under Ubuntu 14 and am using PyCharm (if this might help). The ES node is up and running locally on my computer.
I tried to change the timeout (or with request_timeout) but it is doing nothing. What is weird is the query is working from the terminal, so maybe it is coming for Pycharm.
I am a beginner so maybe I missed something obvious.

Thanks a lot for your help!

```
WARNING:elasticsearch:PUT http://port:9200/data-client_dev/test/2?timeout=60 [status:N/A request:20.040s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elasticsearch/connection/http_urllib3.py", line 78, in perform_request
    response = self.pool.urlopen(method, url, body, retries=False, headers=self.headers, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 608, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 224, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 558, in urlopen
    body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 353, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 979, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1013, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 975, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 835, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 797, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 162, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 142, in _new_conn
    (self.host, self.timeout))
ConnectTimeoutError: (<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fe723d7e550>, u'Connection to port timed out. (connect timeout=10)')
WARNING:elasticsearch:Connection <Urllib3HttpConnection: http://port:9200> has failed for 1 times in a row, putting on 60 second timeout.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create your Elasticsearch client like this, i.e. by putting the host in a list:

```
es = Elasticsearch([{'host': 'localhost', 'port': 9200}])
                   ^                                   ^
                   |                                   |
                add this                           and this
```